# Rack Awareness on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was going through Hadoop. I have questions about Rack Awareness :

1. Is it logical or physical rack?
2. And why for every block of data, two copies will exist in one rack, another copy in a different rack?
3. For example if I have three racks and the replica factor = 3, why it doesn't place each block copy in each rack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racks are logical in Hadoop Rack awareness.

Regarding replica placement policy :

> The purpose of a rack-aware replica placement policy is to improve data reliability, availability, and network bandwidth utilization.
>       Communication between two nodes in different racks has to go through switches. In most cases, network bandwidth between machines in
>   the same rack is greater than network bandwidth between machines in
>   different racks.

when the replication factor is three, HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on one node in the local rack, another on a node in a different (remote) rack, and the last on a different node in the same remote rack.

**This policy cuts the inter-rack write traffic which generally improves write performance.**

The chance of rack failure is  far less than that of node failure; this policy does not impact data reliability and availability guarantees. However, it does reduce the aggregate network bandwidth used when reading data since a block is placed in only two unique racks rather than three.
One third of replicas are on one node, two thirds of replicas are on one rack, and the other third are evenly distributed across the remaining racks. This policy improves write performance without compromising data reliability or read performance.

Please refer the documentation [Hadoop Data replication](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It's default hadoop rack policy to distribute 2 copies on the same rack and 1 on a different rack. But you can change the logic and config in hadoop open source code to make all 3 copies on the different node.

Answer (score 1):

- Logical. You are to provide an external script for Hadoop that converts datanodes' hostnames to rack names.
- Inter-rack bandwidth is an expensive resource (more expensive than bandwidth within the same rack). So, this is a tradeoff between reliability and resource usage.

Comment: why for every block of data, two copies will exist in one rack, another copy in a different rack  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A block write operation is implemented that way. Once you want to write a block of data, NameNode (that knows which DataNode belongs to which rack) will give you three DataNodes to write to. NameNode will choose the DataNodes in a way that two of them will be on one rack, and the third will be on another rack.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it logical or physical rack ?

logical

> And why for every block of data, two copies will exist in one rack, another copy in a different rack ?
>
> For example if I have three racks and the replica factor = 3, why it doesn't place each block copy in each rack?

This provides data availability in the event of a network switch failure or partition within the cluster.

At least one replica is stored on different RAC. If one RAC is not accessible, still Hadoop can fetch data block from other RAC.

Due to replication of data blocks on three different nodes across two different RACs, Hadoop read operations provides high availability of data blocks.

Refer to Apache documentation of [HdfsUserGuide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html) for more details